# Matrix of buttons like Security Pattern Pannel

Tags: android, security, button, matrix, design-patterns

I want to make a matrix of buttons and, while a button gets clicked draw a line that will connect to another button of the matrix.

In factm like the title said, I want a behaviour very similar to the security pattern, at least the appereance.

Is there any place with the source code of the security pattern to see how they did it? 
Or maybe any recommendation for building it on my own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TableLayout. You can place your buttons in it's rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think you want the source of LockPatternUtils.java, although I haven't looked in detail.

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/com/android/internal/widget/LockPatternUtils.java.htm

Answer (score 0):

The official source is here:
http://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/source/browse/src/group/pals/android/lib/ui/lockpattern/widget/LockPatternUtils.java?r=7470bc287cba61198430e3d8aff32196bb5824a0